# can't locate libpython2.7.so.1.0

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install an application called Prism pipeline on Ubuntu 19.10. The installer fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Scripts/PrismInstaller.py", line 65, in <module>
from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Scripts/PrismCore.py", line 68, in <module>
from PySide.QtCore import *
ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

if I run `locate libpython2.7.so.1.0`, it gives me blank result indeed.
if I just run `python`in my terminal, the Python session starts correctly with python 2.7.17, so I'll say that it's installed on my System (I think that's is the default installation that comes with ubuntu).

So after a google research I found that I possibly need to install libpython2.7, but `sudo apt-get install libpython2.7` results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython2.7 : Depends: libpython2.7-stdlib (= 2.7.17~rc1-1) but 2.7.17-1~19.10 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix it? thanks in advance

Comment: Show us commands you use to install so it could be reproducible.

Comment: You could reinstall : `sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7` ... Filelist https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/libpython2.7/filelist

Comment: Make the Linux scripts executable :  `Prism/Prism_setup_Linux.sh, Prism/Prism/{  Linux_Setup_Integrations.sh,  Linux_Setup_Startmenu.sh}` .... The "build / install" command is `sudo Prism_setup_Linux.sh`

Comment: Thank you. So the three script are already executable, and I was infact using `sudo ./Prism_setup_Linux.sh` to install.
`sudo apt install --reinstall libpython2.7` gives me the same error (unmet dependecies and broken packages).

I didn't mentioned it, but if it can help: I run Ubuntu 19.10 with minimal installation, and the only Python-thing I installed was Python3, so apart from it I have the default Python 2 packages that comes with ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Running the following command will install `libpython2.7.so.1.0`:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
```